# what is the meaning of "humanitarian grounds"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *humanitarian grounds*? I see it in the newspaper online, but I don't know the meaning of that.

Comment: ***Ground***: ***matter*** for consideration or debate; field of research or inquiry. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ground.

Comment: 'On humanitarian grounds' = 'in a way that prioritises the exercise of care and compassion for those affected'.

Comment: Because of being human (considering and caring humans). For example, you can apply for permanent presidency of  Canada on a *Humanitarian and Compassionate Considerations*, if your parents reside there.

Comment: Ground up humans -- it's what the 1% uses for coffee.  (OK, it's lousy joke, but I'm having an off day.)

Answer (score 1):

On *humanitarian grounds* means because of humanitarian reasons.

Reference:

[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/)

3) [grounds](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ground_1) : a good reason for doing, believing, or saying something

```
on moral/legal/medical etc grounds

The proposal was rejected on *environmental grounds*.
```